# MySQL: How to find a count of records from one table where date is later than date from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

There are 2 MariaDB tables:

table1

```
|------+----------------------+
| phone | calldate            |
|-------+---------------------+
| 123   | 2020-01-01 17:01:00 |
| 456   | 2020-01-01 17:01:00 |
| 789   | 2020-01-01 17:01:00 |
|------+---------------------+|
```

table2

```
|------+---------------------+
| phone| calldate            |
|------+---------------------+
| 123  | 2020-01-01 16:00:00 |
| 123  | 2020-01-01 17:00:00 |
| 456  | 2020-01-01 17:00:00 |
| 123  | 2020-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 456  | 2020-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 789  | 2020-01-01 18:00:00 |
|------+---------------------+
```

Expected result:

```
|-------+------+
| phone | count|
|-------+------+
| 123   | 2    |
| 456   | 1    |
|-------+------+
```

How to find  a count of records from table2 where calldate is early than calldate from table1  group by  phone?

Comment: It looks like one call is later for both numbers.

Comment: Yes , i made mistake. I edited question

Comment: Does `table1` have only one row with each `phone`?  If not, the solution gets messier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find a count of records from table2 where calldate is later than calldate from table1 group by phone?

This sounds like a `join` and aggregation:

```
select t2.phone, count(*)
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.phone = t1.phone and t2.calldate > t1.calldate
group by t2.phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select t2.phone, count(*) count
from table2 t2 
where exists (
  select 1 from table1 t1
  where t1.phone = t2.phone and t1.calldate > t2.calldate
)  
group by t2.phone
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hUUTyS5UoiN9w4VA1SwZCT/1).
Results:

```
| phone | count    |
| ----- | -------- |
| 123   | 2        |
| 456   | 1        |
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try with a where clause if that is not working  :

```
select count(table2.phone) from table2 t2 
full outer join table1 t1 on t2.phone=t1.phone
where t2.calldate >t1.calldate
group by t2.phone
```